# Syntax error for path asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, file, model-view-controller, syntax

```
public ActionResult OpenDocument(int documentID)
{
    Document doc = Model.DocumentServiceHelper.GetSingleDocument(documentID);

    if (doc != null)
    {

      string destinationPath = "." + doc.FileExtension;


      return File(doc.Data, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(doc.Name), doc.Name + Path.GetFileName(destinationPath));

    }
   return Json("No File", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**doc.FileExtension** is "**xls**" or "**pdf**". I add "**.**" with **doc.FileExtension**.

**string destinationPat**h  Result is **MyFileName.xls** or **MyFileName.pdf**

However

when i return file **doc.Name + Path.GetFileName(destinationPath)** displays below

**"MyFileName.xls--" or "MyFileName.pdf-"** on downloaded file name

How can i correct "**-**" problem (**syntax** problem) according to my code ?

Thanks.

Comment: why not string.Format("{0}.{1}", doc.Name, doc.FileExtension) instead of doc.Name + Path.GetFileName(destinationPath))?

Comment: @IgorSemin same problem occurs i tried your code

Comment: As you are returning a file as the ActionResult, does the file open etc? Is it only a textual display that is incorrect? What is the code in the View you are using for display?